# Why is my td onClick not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm adding a background image to a table dynamically and have a .click function which enables a class that essentially greys out the cell.

```
    var url;
    url = images[i];
   newImage = "url("+url+")";


    document.getElementById('sq'+(i+1)).style.backgroundImage = newImage;
}
$('body').on('click','td', function() {


    alert("Clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass('ui');

    if ($(this).data('value') == 1) {
        $(this).data('value', 0);
    } else {
        $(this).data('value', 1);
    }
```

Here is the css class 'ui'

```
.ui {
visibility: hidden;
 border: 3px solid black;
background-color: #ff1e72 !important;
color: #FFF !important;

}
```

Here is the table html

```
<tr>
                            <td data-value="0" id="sq1"></td>
                            <td data-value="0" id="sq2"></td>
                            <td data-value="0" id="sq3"></td>
                            <td data-value="0" id="sq4"></td>
                            <td data-value="0" id="sq5"></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What is `i`? What is `images`? Have you closed the `on` method? Any error on the console?

Comment: what is your error??

Comment: When do you set this handler? BODY has to be available in DOM at time you set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like this:

#### Update: You should use `$(this).attr("data-value",thevalue);`

```
$(function(){
$("td").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked");    
    $(this).toggleClass('ui');
    
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
    if ($(this).data('value') == 1) {
        $(this).attr("data-value",0);
    } else {
         $(this).attr("data-value",1);
    }
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/mktsapk5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Like said A. Wolff you must enclose jquery in Dom Ready event becouse jquery need to scan the dom before perfoming of any actionLike said A. Wolff you must enclose jquery in Dom Ready event becouse jquery need to scan the dom before perfoming of any action, this must help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('click','td', function() {
        alert("Clicked");
        $(this).toggleClass('ui');

        if ($(this).data('value') == 1) {
            $(this).data('value', 0);
        } else {
            $(this).data('value', 1);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#some-class tbody td" ).on( "click", function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('ui');
   });
});
```

try document ready to fire off jquery with document ready; I'm not sure what's going on with your script. have some class to start digging into html, its a good idea to access based on class names to be precise. you should definitely use tbody for a well structured html. Now this isn't tested. I would try blocks of jquery scripts to test throughout your script to resolve your issue.